# Removing AndroidManifest element with gradle product flavors

Tags: android, gradle

I'm setting up an Android gradle project with a few product flavors. I would like to have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission in all but one of my flavors. I know it is possible to have a particular flavor *add* a permission, but is it possible to have a flavor *remove* one?

The only other solution to this that I can think of is adding the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission to all of my flavors except that one, which seems quite painful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) you can:

1. remove permission with adding to your manifest something like this `<permission android:name="permissionOne" tools:node="remove"/>`
2. and declare separate AndroidManifest.xml parts for each flavor in
   `src/myFlavor/AndroidManifest.xml` which will be merged this main AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Another answer suggests using tools:merge="remove". Which one is correct?

Comment: Cata's solution does not work for me. Maybe it just is outdated

Answer (score 22):

I know this is old but now there is a new attribute called `tools:node="remove"` that enables you to remove a tag from the Manifest.

Declare the header of your manifest as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Also you have to add your tag like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" tools:node="remove" />
```

I hope this helps others.

Source: [HERE](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/04/10/android-gradle-manifest-merge/)

Also Android documentation: [HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html)

**EDIT:**

Edited the answer to match new API changes. Thanks to Martin L. for his comment

Comment: That's part of the answer - but how do you limit the "remove" directive to a particular flavor or build type?  The OP wants the permission to appear in all but 1 flavor, and they're trying to avoid duplicate manifest files.  I see in the Manifest Merger documentation that there's a tools:selector attribute, but it only shows examples related to package names.  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: It's "tools:node=remove", not "tools:merge": <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"
        tools:node="remove" />

Answer (score 1):

gradle merges manifests so probably not. I have solved similar problem (broadcast receivers package names) by removing tag from main manifest and adding it to all specific flavors.