# Does google analytics add wakelock permission?

Tags: android, google-analytics, permissions, android-wake-lock

So i just added Google Analytics to my app's activities. When uploading the new .apk to the play store, it told me that the app now requires 1 more Permission: WAKE_LOCK.

Now I'm 100% sure that this permission is not in my manifest, so it has to be added by Google Analytics. Is there a way to disable that? Or would that ruin google analytics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you added this permission to your manifest file.    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: i did not, and I'd prefer not to use the permission, even if it makes google analytics less reliable. The thing is: the permission is still being added to my apks, and I wonder how to disable that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On Google Play devices, a background service is almost always running as "Google Play Services", so WAKE_LOCK is not required.
>
> On non-Google Play devices, WAKE_LOCK helps keeping the dispatching process / service of Google Analytics alive so it has more chances to report / upload data.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, but how can i disable the permission? It's not in the manifest. Must be added later. Gradle? any idea?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the source?

Answer (score 10):

Try using the "tools" namespace and then explicitly removing the "WAKE_LOCK" permission. I've written up a full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933166/578821) but, in summary:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    ...
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah android.permission.WAKE_LOCK is most definitely being added by Google. They did the same thing with the Fit API adding GPS a while back. LAME