# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging really need a WAKE LOCK permission?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-permissions, wakelock

I notice FCM needs an Android wake lock permission. Could I remove the wake lock permission using?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="remove" />
```

or will it disrupt receiving the data/notification payload?

I was reviewing [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960275/do-i-need-android-permission-wake-lock-for-google-play-services-if-i-only-releas) and started wondering if its needed. I remember in GCM its mandatory.

The other question I have is since wake lock is not a dangerous permission, I think on and after API 23, users won't even see or know about this permission as it will be transparent. Even the Play Store will not show them that the app needs a wake lock, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), the [`WAKE_LOCK` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) seems to have been only *optional* and not mandatory:

> Optionally, the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission if the application needs to keep the processor from sleeping when a message is received.

And nothing is stated in the [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) that `WAKE_LOCK` is needed in some way.

And yes, the app will *not* show that it needs `WAKE_LOCK`. For permissions with Normal Protection levels ([docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous)):

> If an app declares that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the permission to the app.

Comment: ok. and wat about on the google play store ? you know that dialog that usually comes up to show the user what permissions the app is requesting ....  if an app needs a normal permission (and its api 23 or up)  does it still show  in that list ?

Comment: Nope. It's *automatically* granted. :) No point of including it in a prompt for asking permissions when it's already granted.

Answer (score 0):

While AL's answer is correct, I would like to add that on the Play Store listing for the app, it shows the permission under the category "Other":

[image: Under Play store permissions]

I couldn't add the picture in a comment, so I was forced to create an answer.