# Android, how to exclude a specific permission for a specific flavor?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-productflavors

So I have 10 flavors in my android project: fl1, fl2, ..., fl10 with the permissions below. Now I want my fl5 not have the `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`. How to do this?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

I know that I can have a different manifest file in `fl5/AndroidManifest.xml`. And it can include any excessive element for this specific build. But this can be a source of errors and mistakes as I should be careful of syncing every time I add an element to main manifest.

I have searched and found different solutions. But I couldn't implement them in my project because they weren't exact. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my fl5/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.mycompany.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"></uses-permission >
```

And here it is my flavors in `build.gradle` file:

```
  productFlavors {
    fl1 {flavorDimensions "in_1"}
    fl2 {flavorDimensions "in_2"}
    fl3 {flavorDimensions "in_3"}
    fl4 {flavorDimensions "in_4"}
    fl5 {flavorDimensions "in_5"}  
    fl6 {flavorDimensions "in_6"}
    fl7 {flavorDimensions "in_7"}
    fl8 {flavorDimensions "in_8"}
    fl9 {flavorDimensions "in_9"}
    fl10 {flavorDimensions "in_10"}       
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing AndroidManifest element with gradle product flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392593/removing-androidmanifest-element-with-gradle-product-flavors)

Comment: Look at this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did all of it but still I can't get the result. I don't know where I am making a mistake. @MirMiladHosseiny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `tools:node="remove"` in your element. In your case, add the following line in `fl5/AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Take a look at [Removing AndroidManifest element with gradle product flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392593/removing-androidmanifest-element-with-gradle-product-flavors) and [How to remove specific permission when build Android app with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616334/how-to-remove-specific-permission-when-build-android-app-with-gradle) questions.

Comment: I did that, but the permission was still present in that build. Should I do something more?

Comment: In the link you provided, it says in second step that I need to declare a manifest per flavor. Is it necessary? Right now I just have a main manifest, and a fl5/manifest excluding the mentioned permission.

Comment: You need to provide manifest per flavor if you want to change them. If there is no change for a flavor, you don't need to add a new manifest. So your current structure is correct. Please share `build.gradle` and `fl5/AndroidManifest.xml` files.

Comment: I did share them.

Comment: Did you locate `fl5/AndroidManifest.xml` in the correct path?

Comment: Yes. Because when I add a permission to fl5 manifest, it works well.

Comment: Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file, then select `Merged Manifest` tab and find where is node `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>` come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206232/discussion-between-mir-milad-hosseiny-and-saj).

Comment: how exclude something for a specific version of android?

Answer (score 3):

Best and easiest way is to create a different AndroidManifest for each flavor.
To reduce redundancy, you can create an AndroidManifest under the main folder containing all activities, services, etc... and separate AndroidManifest under each flavor's folder containing the permissions for that flavor.

For Example, the fl1 Manifest (located at`app/src/fl1/AndroidManifest.xml`) should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

the fl2 Manifest (located at `app/src/fl2/AndroidManifest.xml`) should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

The main AndroidManifest file (located at`app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`) should look like always but without permissions:

```
<manifest  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- permissions are imported via brand-specific AndroidManifest.xml -->

    <!-- common manifest elements -->
    <application
        android:name=".ui.FSApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SecondActivity/>

        <!-- receiver ->
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.BlogPostReceiver"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It's hard for maintenance.